# Relation between second covariant derivative of Killing vector and Riemann tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, vector-fields

I need to prove that $$D_\mu D_\nu \xi^\alpha = - R^\alpha_{\mu\nu\beta} \xi^\beta$$ where D is covariant derivative and R is Riemann tensor. $\xi$ is a Killing vector.
I have proved that $$D_\mu D_\nu \xi_\alpha = R_{\alpha\nu\mu\beta} \xi^\beta$$
I can't figure out a way to get the required form from my solution. Please suggest a way to get the required form from my solution.

Comment: Not necessarily, the $\mu$ and $\nu$ are switched on the middle two indices of the Riemann tensor, so the negative sign could be due to using the symmetry conditions $R_{\alpha[\beta \gamma \delta]}=0$ etc.

Comment: @Orca Ah, I missed that.

Comment: You're sure about that index placement in your first equation ?